# Create web service proxy dynamically and call its methods

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a requirement to call 52 web services from one java project and this number will increase with time. I am using netbeans 7.3 as development tool. One way to do it is right click project and add web service reference for each service. It is not feasible because for every new web service I will have to add a new reference and redeploy the code. Also all these 52 web services will be calling each other so I will have to enter references for each web service in every other service if I go for this approach.

I hope I have explained the scenario. Now I will ask the question. If I have a url to wsdl file e.g. http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL and I know which method in this web service I need to call, is there a way to parse this wsdl dynamically to create proxy client and after that call a specific method in that web service? I have come accross javaxt API http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/Web_Services which intends to do exactly the same but it is not working properly.

To sum up the question - If I have the wsdl url and I don't want to create compile time stubs but know which methods in that url take what inputs and return what values, can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [javaxt-core](http://www.javaxt.com) library should work. There was a release published 2/24 (version 1.6.0) that includes several updates to the javaxt.webservices package. More information can be found here:

http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/RevisionHistory